# Assert a class was added to an element

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm stuck on writing a unit test for a Vue.js component asserting that a particular CSS class is added to the template.

Here's my template:

```
<template>
  <div id="item-list" class="item-list">
    <table id="item-list-lg" class="table table-hover nomargin hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Included modules</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-bind:id="'list-lg-item-' + item.id"
            v-for="item in items"
            v-bind:key="item.id"
            v-bind:class="itemClass(item)">
          <td class="list-item-name">{{item.name}}</td>
          <td class="list-included-parts">
            <span v-for="part in item.parts" :key="part.id">{{part.name}}, </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here's the Component class (Typescript):

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Item, Items } from '@/models/Item';

@Component
export default class ItemList extends Vue {
    @Prop({required: false}) private items: Item[] = Items;

    public itemClass(item: Item): any {
        return {
            'list-item-details': true,
            'list-global-item': item.isGlobalItem(),
        };
    }
}
```

All fairly simple, and I can see the code is correct: the appropriate items are highlighted in the component at runtime. The unit test, however fails with the message

> Error: [vue-test-utils]: find did not return tr#list-lg-item-id.1, cannot call classes() on empty Wrapper

Here's my test (Typescript again):

```
describe('ItemList.vue', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(ItemList, {
    propsData: { items: Items },
  });

  it('highlights global items in the list', () => {
    Items
      .filter((i) => i.isGlobalItem())
      .map((i) =>
        // E.g. list-item-id.1
        expect(wrapper.find(`tr#list-lg-item-${i.id}`).classes())
          .to.contain('list-global-item'));
  });
});
```

I have tried `find()`ing on just the id, rather than a `tr` with that id, and saw the same effect. Furthermore, if I modify the test to output the HTML from the wrapper, I see the `tr` element with the id set correctly is present in the output.

```
<div data-v-63e8ee02="" id="item-list" class="item-list">
  <table data-v-63e8ee02="" id="item-list-lg" class="table table-hover nomargin hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">
    <thead data-v-63e8ee02="">
      <tr data-v-63e8ee02="">
        <th data-v-63e8ee02="">Name</th>
        <th data-v-63e8ee02="">Included parts</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-v-63e8ee02="">
      <tr data-v-63e8ee02="" id="list-item-id.1" class="list-item-details list-global-item">
        <td data-v-63e8ee02="" class="list-item-name">Foo</td>
        <td data-v-63e8ee02="" class="list-included-parts">
          <span data-v-63e8ee02="">Bar, </span>
          <span data-v-63e8ee02="">Baz, </span>
          <span data-v-63e8ee02="">Qux, </span>
          <span data-v-63e8ee02="">Quux, </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What am I missing? Is this related to the fact the `id` attribute is set dynamically?

Comment: Would items list start at position 0? Because error message in your test is complaining about position 1 being empty which could be true/valid..

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be because the generated values for the id tags contained periods, which need to be escaped in the selector strings, e.g. `list-item-id\.1`.